# get the list of programs currently running on Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, qt, winapi, ubuntu

I want to get the list of programs that shows in the Applications tab of Windows Task Manager(include the application icon and its name)  , I wonder which Windows APIs should I use ?

If I want to do the same thing on Ubuntu ,then which Ubuntu APIs should I use ?

Comment: Try [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/)

Answer (score 2):

for Ubuntu you can see this post:

[How to get list opened windows in PyGTK or GTK in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380784/1982962)

for windows you have the WMI module you can see this post:

[I'm trying to get all the processes and applications that are currently running using Python on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5971743/1982962)

Answer (score 1):

Afaik Qt itself will not allow you to do this, at least it did not in prior versions. To solve this for windows you will have to use win-api `EnumProcesses` while in linux you could use the /proc filesystem, which holds information about running processes

Comment: mine will probably work with c++ not with python only

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the `psutil` library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) or [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) it provides a cross platform set of tools including `ps`.